# Syntax explanation: square brackets in python

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am currently going through the book "Python 3 Object-Oriented Programming by Dusty Phillips". In the book I came across a code block that I am having a hard time understanding as I have not seen it used before. 
It seems to be placing square brackets [] at the end of an if else statement.

I initially thought it was referencing a list and still think this, but want to understand why the syntax is how it is.
I have tried googling this problem as well as looking through stack overflow. Every example or problem that I see have items inside the brackets or are initializing a normal list.

```py
def __init__(self, points=None):
    points = points if points else []
    self.vertices = []
    for point in points:
        if isinstance(point, tuple):
            point = Point(*point)
        self.vertices.append(point)
```

The line that I am not understanding in the code is line 2 where points is defined. Thank you for reading and for anyone who helps.

Comment: Try passing `None` in for `points` (or omitting it, so it uses the default `None` value) and see what happens. What value does `points` get assigned when you don't pass a value in?

Comment: `[]` is an empty list. I suspect that you are confused by the python ternary operator rather than that. `a = b if c else d` is similar to but more readable than (in e.g. Javascript) `a = c ? b : d`

Comment: If points is defined then go with points else initialize to an empty list.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/4996248) about *why* the code is written this way rather than just using `def __init__(self, points=[]):` Understanding that is at least as important as understanding the ternary operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it like this:
Have you ever created an empty list?

```
# Like:
myList = list()
# Or:
myOtherList = []
```

You can (or will) see that both of them are valid ways of creating an empty list.

Now as for the `points = points if points else []` line, this is called a [ternary condidtional operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/394814/1878539). The answer in the link has a great explanation how they work! The short version is, like Cid's answer says: It's an abbreviation of a full if/else statement-block.

Your specific case here basically says:

> If *points* exists, use *points*. Otherwise use []

Or in other words:

> If *points* exists, use *points*. Otherwise use *an empty list*

Comment: The addition of the "ternary conditional operator" is very helpful in understanding how they work. Since I have a good understanding of lists, just not the ternary conditional operator. Thank you for your detailed answer.

Answer (score 3):

`points = points if points else []` is a shorthand for

```
if points:
    points = points # points remains unchanged
else:
    points = []     # points is a new list
```

Comment: Very helpful in taking apart the conditional and seeing it in a different way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[] simply means empty list.
Line 2 says that `points` must be assigned as `points` of argument and assigned as empty list if `points` of argument is None.